# How can I make my md-content scrollable in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-material

I haven't found an answer that works for me... Here's my code. My content doesn't scroll. I'm getting my ng-view from a basic template. It's just a bunch of lorem ipsum intended to extend past the end of the page so that I can test this code.

What do I need to do to make my content scrollable? I can't scroll the page at all.

I am running this on a `grunt serve` dev server. Everything was installed via bower. Ang-material is included properly. Everything *looks* like it is supposed to, it just doesn't scroll.

(As a side note, my FAB was in it's proper place at the bottom-right last night, I just decided that this is more important so I'm not focusing on it's position right now. It's floating in the middle-right of the page.)

```
<body ng-app="webApp" layout="column">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-4dp">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <!-- left side -->
            <span flex></span>
            <!-- right side -->
            <md-button class="md-raised" aria-label="Learn More" ng-href="#/contact">
                Contact Me
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content layout="row" flex>
        <md-content id="content" flex>
            <md-content class="container md-whiteframe-6dp">
                <md-content hide show-gt-sm flex layout-padding class="main-text main-view">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                </md-content>
                <md-content hide show-sm show-xs flex layout-padding class="main-text">
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </md-content>
            </md-content>
        </md-content>

        <div ng-controller="FabCtrl as fab" class="lock-size" layout-align="end end">
            <div class="corner-pad">
                <md-fab-speed-dial md-open="fab.isOpen" md-direction="{{fab.selectedDirection}}" ng-class="fab.selectedMode" ng-mouseenter="fab.isOpen=true" ng-mouseleave="fab.isOpen=false" ng-cloak>
                    <md-fab-trigger>
                        <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary md-hue-4 md-whiteframe-4dp" ng-href="tel:9106507122">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="tooltipVisible">Call Me</md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="phone" size="25"></ng-md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-fab-trigger>

                    <md-fab-actions>
                        <md-button aria-label="email" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-primary md-whiteframe-4dp" href="mailto:jacobkdick@gmail.com">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="tooltipVisible">Email Me</md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="email"></ng-md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <md-button aria-label="phone" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-primary md-whiteframe-4dp" href="tel:9106507122">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="tooltipVisible">Follow Me</md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="twitter"></ng-md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <md-button aria-label="github" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-primary md-whiteframe-4dp" href="https://github.com/jacobkdick" target="_blank">
                            <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="tooltipVisible">Fork Me</md-tooltip>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="github-circle"></ng-md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-fab-actions>
                </md-fab-speed-dial>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</body>
```

EDIT: Just applied the `overflow scroll` tags on my css. Here's a funky result from the bottom-right corner. Both scrollbars are disabled

[scrollbars overlay disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnIVw.png) << click here for the picture

Comment: Apply a custom css class or id with `overflow scroll`?

Comment: The content in the docs example is scrollable https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/content